# Robust approach to plot data using for loop?

Tags: python

My code working well, but the approach is very casual and time-consuming, therefore I am looking for robot approach to plot my data.

Data:

```
df=[
          0          1        2          3
0   168.090   7.079305  180.070  12.529506
1   166.410  15.354978  163.950   9.983409
2   187.730   9.258269  171.155  11.199766
3   173.580   4.312133  175.250   6.919743
4   187.720   8.576663  172.100  12.239626
5   157.360  14.367897  162.630  29.970764
6   194.635  18.099173  187.570   8.637874
7   136.615  11.762037  167.020  17.869660
8   147.340  21.289059  178.920  16.214560
9   153.810  17.341258   98.202   9.402761
10  151.485   6.282759  154.600  12.440025
11  158.075  16.351457  142.745   7.769236
12  132.065   3.127747  146.780  32.469510
13  138.980   3.997909  130.400   8.426905
14  196.100  17.066039  171.205  19.416487
15  163.470  12.064534  173.660  13.579139
]
```

Current plotting approach:

```
fig, (ax1)  = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6,3), sharey=False, dpi=300)
x=0

ax1.errorbar(-0.1, D1.iat[0, 0], D1.iat[0, 1], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, label='Ev_1',color='red')
ax1.errorbar(0.1, D1.iat[0, 2], D1.iat[0, 3], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, color='red')


ax1.errorbar(-0.2, D1.iat[0, 0], D1.iat[0, 1], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, label='Ev_2', color='g')
ax1.errorbar(0.2, D1.iat[0, 0], D1.iat[0, 1], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, color='g')

ax1.errorbar(-0.3, D1.iat[1, 0], D1.iat[1, 1], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, label='Ev_3', color='b')
ax1.errorbar(0.3, D1.iat[1, 2], D1.iat[1, 3], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, color='b')

ax1.errorbar(-0.4, D1.iat[2, 0], D1.iat[2, 1], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, label='Ev_4', color='c')
ax1.errorbar(0.4, D1.iat[2, 2], D1.iat[2, 3], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, color='c')

ax1.errorbar(-0.5, D1.iat[3, 0], D1.iat[3, 1], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, label='Ev_5', color='m')
ax1.errorbar(0.5, D1.iat[3, 2], D1.iat[3, 3], fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, color='m')


ax1.axvline(x=x, color='black', linewidth=3, linestyle='dashdot') 
ax1.set_xlim(-2, 2)
#x1.set_ylim(80,220)

ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

ax1.legend(fontsize=6, loc='best', frameon=True, edgecolor="black", ncol = 3)
```

**How plot looks like:**

[image]

Instead of long script, I am looking for a robust approach to plot the data for both on one plot or multiple subplots.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like a simple for loop?

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
          0          1        2          3
0   168.090   7.079305  180.070  12.529506
1   166.410  15.354978  163.950   9.983409
2   187.730   9.258269  171.155  11.199766
3   173.580   4.312133  175.250   6.919743
4   187.720   8.576663  172.100  12.239626
5   157.360  14.367897  162.630  29.970764
6   194.635  18.099173  187.570   8.637874
7   136.615  11.762037  167.020  17.869660
8   147.340  21.289059  178.920  16.214560
9   153.810  17.341258   98.202   9.402761
10  151.485   6.282759  154.600  12.440025
11  158.075  16.351457  142.745   7.769236
12  132.065   3.127747  146.780  32.469510
13  138.980   3.997909  130.400   8.426905
14  196.100  17.066039  171.205  19.416487
15  163.470  12.064534  173.660  13.579139
'''), sep="\s+")

x=0.1
x_offset=0.1

fig, (ax1)  = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6,3), sharey=False, dpi=300)

for i, (v1, e1, v2, e2) in df.iterrows():
  label=f"Ev_{i+1}"
  ax1.errorbar(x, v1, e1, fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, label=label)
  ax1.errorbar(-x, v2, e2, fmt='o', linewidth=2, capsize=3, label=label)
  x += x_offset

ax1.axvline(x=0, color='black', linewidth=3, linestyle='dashdot') 
# ax1.set_xlim(-2, 2)

ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

ax1.legend(fontsize=6, loc='best', frameon=True, edgecolor="black", ncol = 3)
```

[image]

If you want custom colors, make an array for every row and then access it inside the loop like `color=mycustomcolors[i]`